# startMonitoringForRegion not creating a region

Tags: objective-c, monitoring, region, geofencing

I'm trying to create a geofence and monitor it using CLLocationManager and startMonitoringForRegion:. The problem is, not only is my delegate getting no calls (yes, I've implemented all methods), but the region is not being stored in the [locationManager moniteredRegions] set. A log after running the code below shows:

2012-07-31 13:46:54.208 GeofencingTest[2357:f803] Created regions:

Yes - I've checked for regionMonitoringEnabled and regionMonitoringAvailable.
No - I haven't tried this on a device, only the simulator.
Yes - I can get location updates from CLLocationManager by doing [locationManager startUpdatingLocation] and CLLocation *location = locationManager.location;

Please help! :)

**LocationDelegate.m**

```
- (void) createGeofence:(NSString *)identifier withCenter:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)center withRadius:(CLLocationDistance) radius{
   if ([CLLocationManager regionMonitoringEnabled] && [CLLocationManager regionMonitoringAvailable]){
       CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:center radius:radius identifier:identifier];
       NSLog(@"should be succesful");
       [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
   }

   NSLog(@"Created regions:");
   for (CLRegion *my_region in [locationManager monitoredRegions]){
       NSLog(@"    Region: %@", my_region.identifier);
   }    
}
- (id) init{
   self = [super init];
   if (self){
      locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
      locationManager.delegate = self;
      locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
   }
   return self;
}
```

**SomeOtherClass.m**

```
- (IBAction)createGeofence:(UIButton *)sender{



   float latitude = [latitudeField.text floatValue];
   float longitude = [longitudeField.text floatValue];
   CLLocationDistance radius = [radiusField.text floatValue];

   CLLocationAccuracy desiredAccuracy = [self getAccuracyConvertedToMeters];

   [self.locationManagerObject createGeofence:identifierField.text
                                   withCenter:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude) 
                                   withRadius:radius
                                 withAccuracy:desiredAccuracy];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It might be that when you log the created regions, the region has not been monitored yet. I think you should try to call the delegate methods of the region monitoring and look for the monitored regions there.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Start monitoring for region: %@", region.identifier);
    for (CLRegion *my_region in [manager monitoredRegions]){
        NSLog(@"Region: %@", my_region.identifier);
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: These methods are not being called for me, even if I set the colocation's delegate to self.